# How to create a bot for steam on PHP?

Tags: php, api, bots, steam

I want to create a bot for trade like on `csgolounge.com` or like on other websites. I can't find the manul.

> I found this:  [Steam Web API/IEconService](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API/IEconService)

.
But I don't know how to use it. Please give me the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same link you provide is the answer for your question, https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API

From PHP you'll need CURL extension enabled in order to make requests to this API